# How do I web scrape when there are generated tags?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I am trying to webscrape using axios and cheerio on target. What I want to do is be able to get the price of an item using its url. The problem I am having is that the selector looks like it is generated . So it seems that the selector changes every time. The element looks like this below

`<div data-test="product-price" class="style__PriceFontSize-sc-17wlxvr-0 cYCpyy">$29.99</div>`

The selector looks like this below.

`#viewport > div:nth-child(5) > div > div.Row-uds8za-0.fMgJXz > div.Col-favj32-0.styles__StyledCol-sc-1n8m629-5.bxnpmb.fcZpgY.h-padding-h-default.h-padding-t-tight > div.h-padding-b-default > div:nth-child(1) > div.style__PriceFontSize-sc-17wlxvr-0.cYCpyy`

I have tried using the `div.h-padding-b-default` to parse but I am still not able to parse the price tag. When I am in the browsers console I am able to use this below and I get the price tag.

`document.querySelectorAll('div.h-padding-b-default')[0].firstElementChild.innerText`

but I am not sure if there is a way to translate this to cheerio. I tried `$('div.h-padding-b-default')[0].firstChild.text()` but that does not work for me either. How would you go about getting the price for any item as long as you have the url.

my current code below.

```
axios.get(item.url).then((response) =>{
    let $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
    let itemTitle = $('h1').text()
    let itemPrice = $('div.h-padding-b-default').find('div').find('product-price')
    console.log(itemTitle)
    console.log(itemPrice)
})
```

Comment: Let's assume you've checked `robots.txt` and the Terms of Service of the site and are not doing anything untoward. Axios + Cheerio are parsing the source code of the page -- the text document you see when you select "View source" -- _not_ the computed output once all of the JavaScript has executed -- what you see when you select "Inspect element." For any site that populates content on the client, you need to use a headless browser like PhantomJS or Puppeteer.

Comment: Yes, I guess I will have to use this solution. I was kind of hoping to only use requests since its faster but this should work.

Comment: Watch the network in Chrome DevTools and filter to XHR -- Sometimes you get lucky and all the data you want is in an AJAX call

Comment: Sounds like the javascript isn't running when you get the url. You need to use something like Headless chrome

Answer (score 0):

For that one use:

```
$('div[data-test="product-price"]')
```